# Запросы на сервер через wget

Tags: linux, post, wget

Есть задание:

На сервере хранится файл, разделенный на 16 частей. При отправке на сервер сообщения, содержащего идентификатор, в ответ можно получить 65 байт данных. Первый байт содержит порядковый номер части файла, а оставшиеся 64 байта содержат данные этой части файла. Задача: Собрать полностью и в правильном порядке исходный файл и переслать его md5 сумму в качестве ответа.

Я делаю запрос:

```
wget -t 1 -O out --post-data 'идентификатор' адрес:порт
```

со своим идентификатором и адресом сервера, на что мне приходит ответ из 65 байт. После этого, командой:

```
hexdump -C out
```

проверяю первый байт и командой:

```
dd if=out of=pNum skip=1 count=64 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

записываю в файл (с названием номера части) 64 байта из *out*. Получается набор файлов с названиями типа: *p0, p1, p2, ..., p15*. Далее, командой:

```
cat p0 p1 p2 ... p15 > full
```

восстанавливаю исходный файл, считаю MD5 командой:

```
md5sum full
```

и отправляю преподавателю. На что он отвечает, что MD5 неправильная, а запрос, который я делаю, может содержать паразитные для этой задачи данные.

Что я делаю не так с этим wget запросом?

Comment: Как получаете md5 сумму? строки по 64 байта должны находиться на новой строке? Следует учесть, что появление `\n` влияет на md5sum

Comment: @PotroNik `md5sum full`
Ну файл размером 1024 байта, как и должен, судя по hexdump. \n там нет, как я понял

Comment: есть два варианта - либо файл получается неверный, либо md5 считается неверный. Я бы попробовал сверить файлы напрямую

Comment: @KoVadim все ответы преподавателя "наводящие", скорее всего он не даст мне просто взять и посмотреть исходник

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует преподавателю автора вопроса

Comment: никто не говорит смотреть в  исходники. Но файл с данными можно взять и сверить. Хотя может Вы не полностью файл получаете (или преподаватель неверно посчитал сумму:) )

Comment: У md5sum есть ключик для бинарного или текстового потока, попробуйте пересчитать сумму с ним.

Comment: @0andriy https://ibb.co/SrdKGxk
Одинаковая сумма получается

Comment: Беглое листание документации на _wget_ только добавляет вопросов: почему одна попытка? Нужны ли куки? Как именно выглядит строка _идентификатор_? И потом выложили бы где этот килобайт для анализа.

Comment: Кстати, вместо _hexdump_, пользуйтесь _xxd_.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Сервер не подразумевал общение по http-протоколу. Те байты, что я получал - были частями сообщения об ошибке или другим мусором.